# Laravel Querying Relationship models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to build something like twitter. When a user posts a message, the links, mentions and hashtags are linked to the specific user. I'm using this piece of code:

```
$post = preg_replace('/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/', '<a href="/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $post );
```

Say, for instance, if I posted "Happy New Year @josh #HappyNewYear #2015". Then the link for link in the post would be `<a href = "/josh">@josh</a>`. 
But I've this route:

```
Route::get('/profile{id}', 'UserController@getProfile');
```

How can I change the link in the post by finding out the user which has the username. I've two table `users` and `user_profile` and the `username` field exists in the `user_profile` table which has a OneToOne relationship with `users`. I'm using the Sentry 2 package.

I've another choice. I can change the route to serve the username for profiles but again I've to find the user which has the username.

When I run this:

```
public function getProfile($username) {

    $user = User::whereIn('username', function($query) {
    $query->select('username')
            ->from('user_profile')
            ->where('username', $username);
        })->get();
}
```

I get this bug: Undefined variable $username, it has not been declared.
While I'm getting it in the url.

Trying to get answers to both the questions. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because of the variable scope. To use a variable inside a closure you have to inject it with `use` :

```
$user = User::whereIn('username', function($query) use ($username) {
    $query->select('username')
        ->from('user_profile')
        ->where('username', $username);
})->get();
```

However if you have a relation you can simply do this:

```
$user = User::whereHas('profile', function($q) use ($username){
    $q->where('username', $username);
})->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  just go it running.